# Understanding STL maps in C++

Tags: c++, oop, nested, maps, binary-search-tree

I would like to ask a few questions regarding nested maps in C++. Are nested maps good or bad practice? Does the performance slow down during insertion if a nested map is used? E.g. Data[year][mth][day][time] = some_object. Also, assuming objects can be compared, can a map key be an object? E.g. Data[date] = some_object

Please guide me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: It makes no difference to the efficiency of a map whether it is used nested or not. But a map is a large object which is expensive to copy. So badly written code could end up copying nested maps, but avoid that and I don't see any problem.

Comment: And the answer to your second question is yes. The key can be any object for which a comparison is defined.

Comment: To me `Data[year][mth][day][time] = some_object` doesn't seem like a good use case for nested maps. What's wrong with `Data[datetime] = some_object`? In this case I'd definitely create a DateTime class which I can use as a key for a non-nested map.

Comment: _"...Are nested maps good or bad practice?..."_ is Opinion Based and is therefore off-topic for SO

Comment: @john In a situation where I would like to only iterate through a specific year and month, how should this be done?

Comment: @JinYuChan With johns approach you can do `Data[{y, m, d, t}]`, assuming `datetime` has a suitable constructor.

Comment: For easy iteration like you described I would stick to your nested approach.

Comment: @super But how does one access the data if only year and month are given if the key object does not have day or time?

Comment: @super Ah I see, thanks. My biggest concern using the nested approach is insertion performance.

Comment: @JinYuChan Since `std::map` is ordered you can use `std::map::upper/lower_bound` to get the range of values between two `datetime`s. But as I said, if that is your main concern I would probably stick to your nested approach. I don't see any problem with using nested maps if it fits your needs.

Comment: @JinYuChan I agree, if iterating through particular year or month is a requirement then nested maps seems perfectly reasonable. Of course insertion will take some performance penalty because you have four keys to lookup not one. But there's always compromise.

Comment: @john Thanks for the explanation. Will find a way to get around the search.